# Difference between type and __class__

Tags: python, django, types

Django source code:

```
def new_method_proxy(func):
    def inner(self, *args):
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            self._setup()
        return func(self._wrapped, *args)
    return inner

class LazyObject(object):

    _wrapped = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._wrapped = empty

    __getattr__ = new_method_proxy(getattr)

    def _setup(self):
        # Must be implemented by subclasses to initialize the wrapped object.
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of LazyObject must provide a _setup() method')

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            # We have to use type(self), not self.__class__, because the
            # latter is proxied.
            result = type(self)()
            memo[id(self)] = result
            return result
        return copy.deepcopy(self._wrapped, memo)
```

In `__deepcopy__()` function, the comment:

```
We have to use type(self), not self.__class__, because the latter is proxied.
```

What does it mean? What is the difference between `type()` and `__class__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit further down in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L295):

```
# Need to pretend to be the wrapped class, for the sake of objects that
# care about this (especially in equality tests)
__class__ = property(new_method_proxy(operator.attrgetter("__class__")))
```

Here you see that the `__class__` attribute (which is ultimately just a normal attribute) is overridden with a custom definition. This new definition is a property that returns the value of the proxied class.

`type(obj)` bypasses the new `__class__` property, and returns the `LazyObject` class, instead of the proxied class.